# add facebook like button to a page

Tags: html, facebook

I would like to add the facebook like button on my page.
I have generated some code from facebook developer site.

Now the problem is, when I click like and it sends a post on my facebook feed, it does not take any image from my site where I have the like button.
rather it keeps an empty space for the image but there is no image.

i google about it and found that i need add the following in my header tag of html

```
<meta property="og:image" content="link to image"/>
```

I also did it. But no success.

Is there any other trick that I need to apply ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be nice to show us your website, anyway i know that this method works just fine.

```
<head>
...
<meta property="og:image" content="http://yousite.com/image.jpg" />
...
</head>
```

Also you can try this: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug